# Filesystem access through web interface

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, web

I have an SSH+Samba server so people can access its files from anywhere on the network.

I thought it would be also interesting to provide access through a web interface, so they can access the files even when they don't have access to the VPN or a Samba/SSH client. Something like the Ubuntu One or Dropbox web interface.

The http server could be on the same machine as the SSH+Samba, so it should just provide access to local files and some way to login with their username/password.

Someone knows any software like this?

Answer (score 1):

There is the [WebDAV protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV). It should be possible to use it to get web access to your data. There are also predefined [WebDAV modules for Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dav.html) available.

Answer (score 0):

[WebDAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) is the first thing that comes to mind.  You can use something like [mod_auth_external](http://code.google.com/p/mod-auth-external/) to have your users use their same passwords by using PAM to authenticate.  It is a very good idea to run WebDAV over SSL so your users aren't sending passwords in the clear over the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to install a script for this. Some examples written in PHP:

- [osFileManager](http://www.osfilemanager.com/)
- [PHPfileNavigator](http://pfn.sourceforge.net/)
- [Flashcommander](http://flashcommander.org/flashcommander)

These will offer you a web-based interface, although it may not be as polished as the ones you mention. For these to work, you will of course need a webserver and PHP.